# Remove datatype attribute from meta about tag

Tags: theming, meta-tags

I'm trying to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://dev.van-eldijk.gotpantheon.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.2) my Drupal 7 website on http://validator.w3.org but I can't keep getting the following error:

> Attribute datatype not allowed on element meta at this point.

This is because `<meta about="/frontpage" property="sioc:num_replies" content="0" datatype="xsd:integer" />` automatically gets the 'datatype=xsd:integer' attribute. I want to remove the datatype attribute altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the meta tag isn't the problem. The problem is the validation service and how you use it. After some digging I found [this article](http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/w3c-validation-drupal-7-html5-rdfa). The author suggest using a different validation type namely: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ with the following preset set in the additional options: "HTML5 + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0 + RDFa 1.1 + Microdata". This will validate said meta tags without any errors.

Comment: The presets have changed; use "HTML5 + SVG 1.1 + MathML 3.0 + RDFa 1.1 + Microdata"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what effect this will have on the validity of that particular tag, but you can remove the property by implementing [`hook_html_head_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) (either in your theme or a custom module file):

```
function MYTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  if (isset($head_elements['rdf_node_comment_count'])) {
    unset($head_elements['rdf_node_comment_count']['#attributes']['datatype']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to alter meta tags...

```
// hook_html_head_alter().
function YOUR_THEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  dsm($head_elements); // if you have Devel installed
  var_dump($head_elements); // else use standard PHP dump
}
```